# Lambda Expresssion - using EntityFramework Include() and Any operation?

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-5

The following code is working

```
var queryResults = _db.Projects
           .Include("Participants.Person")
           .Where(Project => Project.Participants.Any(Parti => Parti.Person.FirstName == "test3"));
```

I am dynamically building lambda expression. In order to achieve the above I have to write lots of code.

I would like to achieve the following.

```
var queryResults = _db.Projects
           .Include("Participants.Person")
           .Where(Project => Project.Participants.Person.FirstName == "test3"));
```

Any suggestion please share.

**Edited section following**

I am trying with Any operation. But i m getting  exception in this line. Any suggestions?

MemberExpression propertyOuter = Expression.Property(c, "Participant");

```
ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Participant), "Participant");
Expression left1 = Expression.Property(tpe, typeof(Participant).GetProperty("Person"));
Expression left2 = Expression.Property(left1, typeof(Person).GetProperty("FirstName"));
Expression right1 = Expression.Constant(filter.FieldValue);
Expression InnerLambda = Expression.Equal(left2, right1);
Expression<Func<Participant, bool>> innerFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<Participant, bool>>(InnerLambda, tpe);

MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Participant));

MemberExpression propertyOuter = Expression.Property(c, "Participant");

var anyExpression = Expression.Call(method, propertyOuter, innerFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, its working.

**Lambda expression**

```
var queryResults = _db.Projects
       .Include("Participants.Person")
       .Where(Project => Project.Participants.Any(Participant => Participant.Person.FirstName == "test3"));
```

**Source code to build dynamic lambda expression**

```
 ParameterExpression c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), entityType.Name);
 ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Participant), "Participant");
 Expression left1 = Expression.Property(tpe, typeof(Participant).GetProperty("Person"));
 Expression left2 = Expression.Property(left1, typeof(Person).GetProperty("FirstName"));
 Expression right1 = Expression.Constant(filter.FieldValue);
 Expression InnerLambda = Expression.Equal(left2, right1);
 Expression<Func<Participant, bool>> innerFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<Participant, bool>>(InnerLambda, tpe);

 MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Participant));

 var outer = Expression.Property(c, typeof(Project).GetProperty("Participants"));

 var anyExpression = Expression.Call(method, outer, innerFunction);
```

This helped lot. [Building a dynamic expression tree to filter on a collection property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977895/building-a-dynamic-expression-tree-to-filter-on-a-collection-property)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is working for you.

```
var queryResults = _db.Persons
   .Where( p => p.FirstName == "test3")
   .SelectMany(p => p.Participant.Projects)
   .Include("Participants.Person");
```

**Edit**: or if person has many participants

```
var queryResults = _db.Persons
   .Where( p => p.FirstName == "test3")
   .SelectMany(p => p.Participants.SelectMany(par => par.Projects))
   .Include("Participants.Person");
```

Comment: No, I am not finding sub entities this line .SelectMany(p => p.Participants.<notFindingEntities>)

Comment: have you selected from _db.Persons as suggested or form _db.Projects?

Comment: I selected from _db.Persons only.

Comment: Ok this means person and participant is in a M to N relation, right?

Comment: see edited suggestion. ...SelectMany(p => p.Participants.SelectMany(par => par.Projects))...