# Building a dynamic expression tree to filter on a collection property 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, filtering

Maybe this is a duplicate thread, but I am going to try, because there is a tiny difference.

I am trying to build a dynamic expression to filter a collection property.

The code:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
} 

public class TestFilter
{
    public TestFilter()
    {
        var itens = new List<TestEntity>();

        itens.Add(new TestEntity { ID = 1, Name = "Test1", Values = new List<string> { "V1", "V2" } });
        itens.Add(new TestEntity { ID = 2, Name = "Test2", Values = new List<string> { "V6", "V3" } });
        itens.Add(new TestEntity { ID = 3, Name = "Test3", Values = new List<string> { "V4", "V5" } });
        itens.Add(new TestEntity { ID = 4, Name = "Test4", Values = new List<string> { "V2", "V3" } });

        itens = itens.Where(e => e.Values.Any(c => c.Equals("V2"))).ToList();

        **//Result IDs: 1, 4**
    }
}
```

The filter above will give me IDs **1 and 4** as result.

I want to filter entities where exists a certain value in the collection "Values".

So far, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977895/building-a-dynamic-expression-tree-to-filter-on-a-collection-property) thread, but didnt realize how it can be done.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: So you want to make the expression in `c=> c.Equals("V2")` dynamic right?

Comment: I want to make e => e.Values.Any(c => c.Equals("V2")). Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect in result?

Comment: Please provide the method signature (arguments, return type) you are looking for.

Comment: Ivan, I want to build a dynamic expression like this one: e => e.Values.Any(c => c.Equals("V2")). For better understanding, here is the fiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wgETgq

Comment: You don't get the point. Dynamically means you have something that is dynamic - property name, value list etc. From your examples it's not clear what is the dynamic part and how it is defined. This is the information that I was (and still) asking you.

Comment: Dynamic property, in this case, is "Values". Dynamic value list: "V2". e => e.Property.Any(c => StringValueProp.Equals(dynamicValue))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are seeking for a method which given a collection property name and value will produce `Where` predicate like `e => e.Collection.Any(c => c == value)`.

You can use the following extension method (hope the code is self explanatory):

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string collectionName, object value)
    {
        var e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var collection = Expression.PropertyOrField(e, collectionName);
        var itemType = (collection.Type.IsIEnumerableT() ? collection.Type :
            collection.Type.GetInterfaces().Single(IsIEnumerableT))
            .GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var c = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "c");
        var itemPredicate = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal(c, Expression.Constant(value)),
            c);
        var callAny = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new Type[] { itemType },
            collection, itemPredicate);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callAny, e);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }

    private static bool IsIEnumerableT(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsInterface && type.IsConstructedGenericType &&
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
    }
}
```

like this:

```
itens = itens.AsQueryable().WhereAnyEquals("Values", "V2").ToList();
```

If you step through the code, the variable `predicate` contains the expression you are asking for.

Comment: Ivan, that is beatiful! Thank you so much!