# Call custom filtering method on IQueryable

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I have this linq query (using linq 4.3.0):

```
return ExecuteODataQuery(Db.AdvisorFees, f => f.Advisor);
```

Implemented as follows:

```
protected IQueryable<TType> ExecuteODataQuery<TType>(IQueryable<TType> queryFunc, Func<TType, Advisor> advisorFunc) where TType : Entity
    {
        var systemAccount = GetSystemAccountThrow();

        var results = queryFunc.Where(x => x.Active).AsEnumerable().Where(x => CheckAdvisorOrChannel(systemAccount, advisorFunc(x)));

        return results;
    }
```

This is my custom method:

```
        public static bool CheckAdvisorOrChannel(SystemAccount systemAccount, Advisor advisor)
    {
        return (systemAccount.IsChannelSystemAccount ? systemAccount.Channel.Code == advisor.Channel.Code : systemAccount.Advisor.Code == advisor.Code);
    }
```

This currently works. If I remove the AsEnumerable() I get a LinqToEntities not supported exception on my custom method. I cannot use AsEnumerable() as I have too many records and do not want to do the rest of the filtering in memory. Is it possible to call a custom method on IQueryable instead? I've been playin with extension methods and expressions but have not managed to get this working yet. Any pointers?

**I would prefer to not use expression trees as much as possible.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a dynamic expression tree to filter on a collection property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977895/building-a-dynamic-expression-tree-to-filter-on-a-collection-property)

Comment: @barakcaf Thanks, I did see that, I was hoping there was a solution without using expression trees.

Comment: You can't get away from expressions but you don't necessarily have to manually construct a tree. Where on IQueryable takes an Expression so you can just call a custom method that returns an Expression of the right type and just define it in the method.

Comment: @Mant101 I've been trying with expressions. The problem is the advisorFunc(x). I get a Not Supported exception. Linq to Entities can't convert it into a store expression. How would I handle that?

Comment: If you want to be flexible you are going to need to make the advisorFunc an expression. Then take the body and use that in a second expression that creates the conditional operator. How many values does it need to have and are they likely to change? Can you get away with a switch statement and a set of hard coded expressions? Thats ugly but if you want to avoid expression trees it will work.